# Creating a distance matrix from sets of xyz coordinates (python)

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics

I have a list of xyz coordinates of different points from a PDB file assigned to variable x. Here is a snippet of what it looks like

```
[ 8.721 15.393 22.939]
[11.2   13.355 25.025]
[11.045 15.057 28.419]
[13.356 13.814 31.169]
[12.54  13.525 34.854]
[14.038 15.691 37.608]
[16.184 12.782 38.807]
[17.496 12.053 35.319]
[18.375 15.721 34.871]
[20.066 15.836 38.288]
[22.355 12.978 37.249]
[22.959 14.307 33.724]
[24.016 17.834 34.691]
[26.63  16.577 37.161]
[29.536 18.241 35.342]
[27.953 21.667 35.829]
```

I would like to use these points to compute a distance matrix. I have tried to use the SciPy distance_matrix function, however it does not appear to support xyz coordinates, only x and y coordinates. Is there a good way to compute this distance matrix manually?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [biopython](https://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ) `Bio.PDB` to get these atoms then you can get the distance between 2 atoms by simply subtracting the two atoms `distance = atom1 - atom2`. 
If you really want to get the distance on your own then that is also simple, by using the formula `d = sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 + (z2 - z1)**2)`.

You just need to loop over to get a distance matrix using one of the `distance` method above:

```
dist=[[0]*len(array[0])]*len(array)  
for i in range(len(array)-1):  
    for j in range(i+1,len(array)):  
        dist[i][j]=distance(array[i],array[j])
```